# Is there a R code that can detect and separate strings containing characters that are similar?

Tags: dplyr, stringr

[image]

I have a dataset (with 100k rows) with strings that contain almost similar names, but I need to separate the names.

```
fertilizer_name<-c('Urea (inorganic)', 'solid manure (organic)')
df1<-data.frame(fertilizer_name)
```

I have tried the grep function, but since organic is contained in the Inorganic, then it filters both organic and inorganic as follows

```
df1 %>% filter(grepl('Organic', fertilizer_name))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just exclude the `inorganic`

```
df1 %>% filter(grepl('Organic', fertilizer_name) & !grepl('Inorganic', fertilizer_name))
```